# SASS/SCSS: Refer to property without using an intermediate variable

Tags: sass

Is it possible to refer to a property previously defined in a selector without introducing an intermediate variable?

I'd like to say something like:

```
.foo {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 300px - $padding;
}
```

I know that $padding syntactically looks for a defined variable, I only use it in the above example to illustrate what I want to achieve in functionality.

The above example would be equivalent to this:

```
.foo {
  $padding: 15px;
  padding: $padding;
  width: 300px - $padding * 2;
}
```

Comment: also want it in Sass.

Comment: Related: [Sass GitHub issue #521](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/521)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you can't, and it would be great.

I haven't tested, but as far as I know the only css pre-processor that can do that is [stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/). Look at the [variable section](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/docs/variables.html) in its documentation, where it says **Property Lookup**. It works that way:

```
.foo {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 300px - @padding * 2;
}
```

But no, in Sass you can't, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: This is exactly the syntax I want in sass. I was afraid it wouldn't be possible. Time to make a feature request.

Comment: I second that, it would be incredibly useful in some situations (such as mixin hover classes that dynamically shift the background-image position by the height of the parent element)!

Comment: Still true in 3.5?

Comment: You can do this in stylus! :)

Answer (score 3):

If its an option to use an other preprocessor then scss, I really recommend using [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs). There is a feature called [Property lookup](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/variables.html#property-lookup) which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Since when is it appropriate to answer a question for a different technology?  "How can I do X with MySQL?" "You can't, but database Y supports that!"

Comment: You're probably right.

But since there is no option in SASS to do this maybe it's an option for the fellow reader to switch the preprocessor.

Comment: Whenever a solution is not available in the boundaries of the question, I think it's more than fair to offer suggestion about where to find the feature requested.